# Algorithm to find geohashes which satisfy query condition

Tags: c++, algorithm, geolocation

I have an application where I need to query geohashes by specifying the bounding rectangle. Since geohashes map 2D to 1D is there a method by which I may find the prefixes of all geohashes which satisfy the query condition (bounding rectangle). I tried to google but I did not find any algorithm.

It will be great if there is some library which does that for me efficiently in C/c++. Even if there is no library then too I can can work with an algorithmic solution.

Comment: You might want to define geohashes here; I for one am unfamiliar with them. Alternatively, look up whether they are preimage resistant. If they are, your best bet is enumeration, which may be all but useless if the domain of the hash is ginormous or even infinite.

Comment: Is the bounding rectangle itself specified by a geohash?

Comment: @mrmcgreg Yes, the bounding rectangle is itself specified by a geohash.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18330/would-it-be-possible-to-use-geohash-for-proximity-searches)

Comment: @davidstrachan Its not a duplicate as proximity search problems are very different from bounding box problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix will be the geohash of the bounding rectangle.

In geohashing the even bits of a geohash correspond to latitude and the odd bits correspond to longitude. As we proceed from left to right we refine the interval that the geohash specifies.

Consider a hypothetical geohash with bits `110` corresponding to longitude. This tells us that we're interested in points in the bottom half (`90` to `135`, the `0`) of the top half (`90` to `180`, the second `1`) of the top half (`0` to `180`, the first `1`) of all longitudes (`-180` to `180`). So by specifying a longer string you just further refine the interval.

Since the bounding rectangle is specified as a geohash you don't need to do anything at all.